# Do while loop in C or C++ for multiple inputs

Tags: c++

Following is the code snippet i'm working, although I need 4 values for my input, until the user types correct value, it should keep asking, any inputs on the same
Thanks in advance

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int days;
        float peny;

        do{
                printf("Enter Number of days: ");
                scanf("%d", &days);
        }
        while ((days != 28) || (days != 29) ||(days != 30) ||(days != 31));
        printf("Number of days are %d", days);


}
```

Answer (score 5):

Think about what your loop condition is saying.  It will keep looping whilst any of those individual conditions is still true, or to put it another way, looping *until* all of them are false simultaneously.  Is that possible?

Comment: Exactly, I did not think it that way Oli, thanks for picking that up, as Jonathan said in the snippet.
I did not think it that way, since the loop is waiting for all conditions to be false, and the culprit was the OR condition instead of the AND condition.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

while((days<28)||(days>31)); // ie. while days are illegal because to low OR too high

Answer (score 2):

The condition

```
(((days != 28) || (days != 29) ||(days != 30) ||(days != 31)))
```

in your `do-while` loop will always be true because the value of days can not be 28, 29,30, 31 at the same time. The or operator could be changed to and:

```
while ((days != 28) && (days != 29) && (days != 30) && (days != 31));
```

Comment: Yes, I did not think of this in a way, since it will keep on looping if I put the conditional OR operator.
The conditional AND works perfectly fine, this is really helpful.

Thanks Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

Always test the return status from `scanf()`; if it doesn't tell you 1, it is failing, perhaps because the user typed `a` instead of `31`.

Consider counting the number of consecutive failures (and bailing out if the count gets too high) so the user doesn't get frustrated.

Consider using `fgets()` to read the input and `sscanf()` to parse it; it is generally easier to manage.

Consider using C++ for C++ and C for C; what you show is a C program rather than a C++ program (though it can indeed be compiled with C++, unless my eyes are deceiving me).  In general, the languages are very different.

Include a newline at the end of the final `printf()`.

Comment: "what you show is a C program rather than a C++ program" - I think that may need some clarification for someone just starting out (as evidence by the question itself).  (Also, don't C programs need "return 0;" - unlike C++?  ;-P)

Comment: Umesh - in C++, following Jonathan's advice, you get something like `std::string s; int num_failures = 0; while (true) { std::cout << "Enter days in month: "; if (getline(std::cin, s)) { std::istringstream iss(s); if (iss >> days) if (days >= 28 && days <= 31) break; else  std::cerr << days << " is never a valid number of days in a month.\n"; else std::cerr << "you need to enter a number\n"; if (++num_failures == 3) { std::cerr << "Giving up - goodbye\n"; exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } }` - it'll look a little better when indented properly... :-)

Comment: @TonyDelroy: In C89 (eg with Microsoft Visual C), you do indeed need a `return 0;` at the end of `main()`.  Sadly, C99 allows you to omit that from `main()` -- but only `main()` -- for conformity with C++98 (I assume).  So, it is a valid program in the old (C99 -- as opposed to very old C89 or new C11) standards.  I take it to be a C program precisely because it is using functions such as `scanf()` for which C++ has arguably better alternatives (or, at least, notationally distinctively different alternatives; I'm referring to the `>>` and `<<` input and output operators, of course).